# warning, "number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given

Tags: decimal

I get this error from this line can anyone tell me who can resolve this problem.

```
function format_numeric($str) {

    if(empty($str) && $str!=0) return;
    global $appearance_settings;
    $decimals = $appearance_settings['number_format_decimals'];
    $point = $appearance_settings['number_format_point'];
    $th_separator = $appearance_settings['number_format_separator'];
    $result = number_format($str, $decimals, $point, $th_separator); //THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: You are passing a string to a function that does not take a string. What do you want `format_numeric` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your variable names you're passing a string into this function, but as the message says, `number_format()` requires a `double`.

You can force the issue by adding

```
$str = floatval($str);
```

as the first line of your function.

This assumes that your `$str` variable contains something that can be coerced to a `double`. If it doesn't you might see other errors.