# PHP deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double

Tags: php

Line 3 is what´s producing the error in subject:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
$theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1))
... (truncated)
```

And this is what $lat1 is "made of":

```
$latitude = $_GET["latitude"]; 
...
```

After which I´ve inserted:

```
settype($latitude, "double");
settype($lat1, "double");
```

Then later it calls the functions where the error occurs:
    $location = distance($latitude, $longitude, $contactlat, $contactlong, 
    "K");
    ...

The value for ["latitude"] is something like this: 65.96669666666666

As you can see, I tried converting the value to double, but with no luck. Also, in the program sending the data to the php script I made sure that it´s a double value, which however obviously has no effect as it´ll come through as a string nomatter what.
I know it´s only a warning, but since I need my debug messages, I want to get rid of this warning.
So, does anybody know how I can turn $lat1/$latitude into a double?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue with this simple test `$n='65.96669666666666';settype($n,'double');var_dump($n,sin(deg2rad($n)));` issue could be elsewhere. after "_deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double_" what does it say was given?

Comment: If you put an ```echo $lat1;``` right before the line with the error, is it the value you expect? You might check the stack to see if the function is being called from where you expect.

Comment: @ Sloan Thrasher Thanks, then it says 65.966696666667, so it´s been rounded up a bit even.

Comment: @ Scuzzy The full error is:  Warning: deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, it appears that I´d overlooked an answer which seems to have helped me here:

[warning, "number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642812/warning-number-format-expects-parameter-1-to-be-double-string-given)

So in the function, as the first thing, I now have:

```
$lat1 = floatval($lat1);
$lat2 = floatval($lat2);
$lon1 = floatval($lon1);
$lon2 = floatval($lon2);
```

.. and the warning is gone!

Comment: using `settype()` before `deg2rad()` should have done the same job... strange